Route cases to specific queue based on language
I have a requirement where our customers can send emails in different languages and we have Email-to-cases to assign them to a queue. I need to change the process to route the cases to different queues based on the Language. I have tried "Route Email2Case" appexchange app in sandbox, but it doesn't seem to fit for my requirements due to the following reasons.
1) This needs google translate API which needs a GCP account with associated payment profile and I don't want to do that.
2) This App is using the Email Services, not the standard functionality of Email-to-case

Is there any other way I can achieve this functionality?
Thanks in advance.

If you can't find an app to do this, you'll need to build it yourself.  Note that Salesforce doesn't have built-in translation services, so you have to use a 3rd party service like Google Translate API.

Apex does not have any solution to detects languages. If I were you I would try to collect all greetings in my language, for example
final List<String> ITALIAN_GREETINGS = new List<String>{'Ciao', 'Buongiorno', 'Buonasera', 'Salve', 'Buonanotte'};

Then add a method in after trigger
static Boolean isItalian(Case myCase) {
    for(String greeting: ITALIAN_GREETINGS) {
        if(myCase.subject.containsIgnoreCase(greeting)) {
            return true;
        }
        if(myCase.description.containsIgnoreCase(greeting)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

Not professional but cheap and will work for most cases.
